# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error 0x80070003 Cannot read configuration file

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I'm getting the above error when I publish my application and move it from development to production server. Below are the error details.

> Detailed Error Information
>
> Module IIS Web Core
>
> Notification BeginRequest
>
> Handler Not yet determined
>
> Error Code 0x80070003
>
> Config Error Cannot read configuration file
>
> Config File \?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WorkmenCompTest\web.config
>
> Requested URL http://localhost:80/wictest
>
> Physical Path C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WorkmenCompTest
>
> Logon Method Not yet determined
>
> Logon User Not yet determined

This website used to work previously but recently the published version stopped working due to this error. As far as I can tell, the only change was installing iTextSharp and iTextSharp xmlworker through nuget.

I have tried, without success:

1. giving modify permission on the site folder to Everyone
2. checking the web.config file, and using an older version of the web.config file (from when the site worked).
3. uninstalling iTextSharp and iTextSharp XMLWorker

The project still runs without issue from Visual Studio.

Comment: where have you put the published version of your code? desktop?? or downloads folder?

Comment: @Mysterio11 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WorkmenCompTest

Comment: Correction. I actually placed it at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WorkmenComp-Test, and error is basically IIS saying that it couldn't find anything in the WorkmenCompTest path.

Comment: well thats why i asked where it was placed

Comment: The naming error wasn't obvious when I asked the question so it didn't occur to me. I only noticed it later on. Still, upvote for being in the right direction.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is solved. The error was caused by the folder name not matching the path for the virtual directory. Oh wow I feel dumb.

Comment: I had exactly the same issue and spent hours looking for an answer... Do you know why the physical and virtual path have to match? I don't think this is the case for on iis6 but apparently so on iis8.

Comment: I had the same issue, I too feel stupid. In my case it was because I renamed a folder in the path. I wish the error message was could not find file, or path doesn't exist or something like that. That might make it easier to resolve these sorts of ID_10_T/PEBCAC errors.

Answer (score 4):

Check the `applicationhost.config` file under - `.vs\lpsWeb-UI\config` folder of your application root.

Under **sites section** of the config file check what the *physical path* points to.

If you modify those you should be able to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of different physical path in the IIS.To change the physical path of application content

You can perform this procedure by using the user interface (UI), by running Appcmd.exe commands in a command-line window, by editing configuration files directly, or by writing WMI scripts.
User Interface
To use the UI

```
Open IIS Manager. For information about opening IIS Manager, see Open IIS Manager (IIS 7).

In the Connections pane, expand the Sites node and click to select the site in which your application runs.

In the Actions pane, click View Applications.

On the Applications feature page, select an application from the list and then click Basic Settings in the Actions pane.

In the Physical path box, change the path of the application content.

Click OK.
```

Answer (score 0):

DefaultAppPool application pool runs under the Network Service account. This account is local to the computer and this account does not exist on another computer. Make sure that you configure the DefaultAppPool application pool to use an account that is a domain user. Then, you can use the same account on the WorkmenComp file server. Alternatively, you can create a workgroup account on the WorkmenComp file server.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting this HTTP Error 500.19 error when I am giving physical path as Z:\App_Live in IIS

[image: error path]

Instead of using z:\ ,
I used network path \\server\share\live_folder in the IIS physical path – something like this \\server\share\wwwroot\inetpub\wwwroot

[image: Network path]

Also you may need to specify username/password in "connect as".

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the .vs folder and rebuild the solution. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `.vs` folder in your project, and then rebuild the solution. It worked for me too.