# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error - 0x80070003

Tags: iis-8

When I attempt to run a website I receive the following error message:-

> "The requested page cannot be accessed because the related
>   configuration data for the page is invalid."

I am Using IIS8.5

At the bottom of the error message there is further information that indicates that the error lies within the web.config file. I have had a look at the file but cannot find anything of note?

Detailed Error Information:

```
Module IIS Web Core  
Notification Unknown  
Handler Not yet determined  
Error Code 0x80070003  
Config Error Cannot read configuration file   
Config File \\?\D:\Inetpub\SupplierSearch\web.config

Config Source:
-1: 
 0:
```

Any assistance will be nuch appreciated.

Regards Peter

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/oob-500.html If you don't know what is IIS OOB, read it to get started.

Comment: You can get your answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36879981/http-error-500-19-internal-server-error-0x80070003-cannot-read-configuration-f